Converting longitude latitude file into a dwg file
I have a file with list of rectangles and lines  defined by their latitude and longitude. I want to generate a DWG file from this list.
Is there an API in forge that will help me do this?
If so, what is the pricing?
Thank you
Olivier

You need to write a custom program in .NET or C++ to do this using AutoCAD API, and execute this program on APS Design Automation.
Geographical Coordinates with respective Lat\Long for given Cooridnate Reference System the point data-set maybe very large, it is need not require to place with same magnitude in AutoCAD drawing, you can use GeoCoordinateTransformer API to transform the GeoCooridnate Point to WCS Point.
 [CommandMethod("PlotCoords")]
    public static async void PlotCoords()
    {

       var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(DLLDirectory, "sample_x_y"), "*.json");
        
        var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var ed = doc.Editor;
        ed.PointMonitor += Ed_PointMonitor;
        var db = doc.Database;
        if (!HasGeoData(db)) { return; }
        GeoCoordinateTransformer transformer = GeoCoordinateTransformer.Create("WGS84.PseudoMercator", "LL84");
        using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            if(FLoodProbablityMapper != null)
            {
                FLoodProbablityMapper.Clear();
            }
            dynamic floodData;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FLOOD_POINT_URL)) {

                floodData = await FloodData.FromUrl(FLOOD_POINT_URL);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(var file in files)
                {
                    floodData =  FloodData.FromJson(file);
                    var floodPoints = floodData.GetFloodPoints();
                    // Get the drawing's GeoLocation object
                    var gd = tr.GetObject(db.GeoDataObject, OpenMode.ForRead) as GeoLocationData;
                    foreach (var point in floodPoints)
                    {
                        if (point.Prediction == 1)
                        {
                            var geoPoint = new Point3d(point.X, point.Y, 0.0);
                            Point3d targetPt = transformer.TransformPoint(geoPoint);
                            Point3d wcsPt = gd.TransformFromLonLatAlt(targetPt);
                            var c = GetColorIntensity(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0), point.Probability);
                            DrawPoint(c, wcsPt, point.Probability);
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }                
            tr.Commit();            

        }            
    }

Refer code sample at https://github.com/MadhukarMoogala/PlottingGeoCoordinates/tree/master
On Getting Started with APS Design Automation
Refer https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/
